# Paging using REST/OData with SP 2013

Tags: 2013, rest, paging, odata

I'm trying to do paging on a document library (also trying this on a list) with SP 2013 using REST/OData but I can't seem to get the [skipping](http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#QueryStringOptions) of items working.

Here are some examples of URLs that I'm trying on my own SP 2013 farm and it also doesn't work on my Office 365 2013 Dev Preview farm. Results are returned and $top and $orderby work fine but it never skips any items. i.e. I can take the $skip out of the URL and I get the same result.

```
http://sp15/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('FAQ')/Items?$skip=2&$top=2&$orderby=ID
http://sp15/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('FAQ')/Items?$skip=2
http://sp15/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('FAQ')/Items?$skip=2&$top=2

http://sp15/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items?$skip=2&$top=2&$orderby=ID
http://sp15/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items?$skip=2&$top=2&$orderby=ID desc
```

etc.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with REST but try the old syntax:
Example: *http://sp15/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/FAQ?$skip=4&$top=2*

Comment: saw this old post and found useful

Comment: Hey have any idea about get items by page of List of sharepoint.?

Answer (score 15):

Currently `$skip` query option is **not** supported in SharePoint 2013/Online.

According to [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](http://Use%20OData%20query%20operations%20in%20SharePoint%20REST%20requests):

> The `$skip` query option does not work with queries for SharePoint
>   **list items**.

But you could utilize `$skiptoken` query option to return paged results as demonstrated below.

Format:  `$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=<last item id to skip>&$top=<items count>`

**Example**

The example demonstrates how to retrieve the limited count of items (2 items) with id equals or greater `2`  from `Pages` library:

```
function getPagedItems(webUrl,listTitle,startItemId,itemsCount)
{
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle +  "')/items?$skiptoken=" + encodeURIComponent('Paged=TRUE&p_SortBehavior=0&p_ID=' + (startItemId-1) + '&$top=' + itemsCount);
    return executeRequest(endpointUrl,'GET');
}


getPagedItems('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/','Pages',2,2)
.done(function(data){
    if(data.d.results.length == 0){
        console.log('Items not found');
        return;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++){
        var item = data.d.results[i];
        console.log(item.Title);
    }   
});
```

where

```
function executeRequest(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    if (typeof headers == 'undefined'){
        headers = {};
    }
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(method == "POST") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

Comment: This is the actual answer for SharePoint list items... not the accepted one, or the most upvoted one (which references a comment that seems to no longer exist...)

Comment: Link to documentation is broken. Actual link is: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#page-through-returned-items

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, none of the above solutions work - this could be because I was attempting this using an external list. To implement paging, I added ?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&$top=100 to the end of the URI. The URI for the next page will be included under JSON.d.__next. Once the last page is reached __next will not be present

Comment: Keep in mind, that the `JSON.d.__next` will only be available if `odata=verbose` is set on `accept` header. Without that, `d` is missing (naturally....) and `__next` will be called `odata.nextLink`, so it needs to be accessed like `JSON["odata.nextLink"]`

Answer (score 4):

I see the same issue on SP2013 online with the new OData V3 _api endpoint. For CRUD operation it might be better to use the OData v2 listdata.svc endpoint for the time being.

Comment: Paging sounds like something that will be added to the _api endpoint at somepoint soon - I'd go with this solution but make sure you pattern it in such a way so that you can swap out with code that DOES run on _api when that capability is added, it'll keep your code current and fully supported/upgradeable for vNext.

Answer (score 4):

Vadim's response is very close, but his query string is off a bit. The issue isn't really his, its Microsoft's as they are not being consistent with their URI escaping.

I used the Postman extension for Chrome and by examining the __next value returned when using $top (which is alternative approach worth considering) I noticed that there is an ampersand that is not escaped properly in the __next values. Using that approach I was able to get pagination with 2013 REST OData calls working. Here is the relevant code to use in conjunction with Vadim's response.

```
var queryString = "?%24skiptoken=Paged%3DTRUE%26p_ID%3D" + (startItemId - 1) + '&%24top=' + itemCount;
```

Comment: Does this still work if you apply an "orderby" some other field than the ID?

Comment: The p_ID value is paged ID, not the list item's ID (I think). The list I was testing on was sorted by modified date and things seemed to be coming back as expected but I must confess to not looking closely.

Answer (score 3):

The $skip parameter does not work in SharePoint 2013 for list items. It only works for collection of data (like list collections, ecc..).
See my comment at the end of this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d4b5c277-ed50-420c-8a9b-860342284b72.aspx