# SharePoint 2013 REST how to add pagination?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I am using SharePoint 2013 REST to display my list data in a table

My list is getting long and how can I have pagination links blow my table?

my code:

```
<script> 
 var app = angular.module('SmartphoneOSList', ['ngSanitize']);  
 app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $http) {  
 $http({  
    method: 'GET',  
    url: "https://myserver/sites/testdev/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Announce')/items",  
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }  
   }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
    $scope.items = data.d.results;  
    $scope.displayFormUrl =  "https://myserver/sites/testdev/Lists/Announce/DispForm.aspx";  
   }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
    //...
  });  
 });  
 </script>  


<h1>Welcome</h1>  
<div ng-app="SmartphoneOSList">  
    <table class="table table-bordered" ng-controller="ListController">   
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">  
        <td><a href="{{displayFormUrl}}?ID={{item.ID}}">{{item.Title}}</a></td>
        <td ng-bind-html="item.Content"></td>  
      </tr>  
    </table>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Get item count with `/ItemCount`.
2. Define a page count you want, like 30, and devide ItemCount on that to get page count.
3. Loop it with `ng-repeat`
   `<div ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-click="reload(page)">{{page}}</div>`.
4. Reload items (`$scope.items = ...`) where you append `"$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=" + page` and `$top=30` to your query.

### Example

Here is a somewhat simplified example based on your code. Note I use underscore for [`range`](http://underscorejs.org/#range) and default announcement list (so Body instead of Content). Tested on SharePoint Online.

```
app.controller('ListController', function($scope, $http, $q) {
  var listUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Announce')/";
  var itemLimit = 10;

  $scope.load = function(page) {
    $scope.activePage = page;

    $q.all({
      items: $http.get(listUrl + "Items", {
        params: {
          $select: "Title,Body",
          $top: itemLimit,
          $skiptoken: "Paged=TRUE&p_ID=" + ((page - 1) * itemLimit)
        }
      }).then(function(res) {
        return res.data.value;
      }),
      itemCount: $http.get(listUrl + "ItemCount").then(function(res) {
        return res.data.value;
      })
    }).then(function(res) {
      $scope.items = res.items;
      var pageCount = Math.floor(res.itemCount / itemLimit) + 1;
      $scope.pages = _.range(1, pageCount + 1);
    });
  };

  $scope.load(1);
});
```

---

```
<div ng-controller="ListController">  
  <table class="table table-bordered">   
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">  
      <td>{{item.Title}}</td>
      <td ng-bind-html="item.Body"></td>  
    </tr>  
  </table>  

  <nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-class="{active: activePage === page}">
        <a href="#" ng-click="load(page)">{{page}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: If the item count is really large, you should use the $skip and $top directives in your REST query as described on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx#sectionSection6).

Comment: I don't think `$skip` works @pholpar, my example above does, it's how I do it on SharePoint online at least (just look at `_next` when you query `/Items`).

Comment: You are right regarding the "new" _api interface:
"It is a known that the $skip functionality isn't available yet in the service" :-(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305776/office-365-sharepoint-api-skip-skiptoken-functionality
However, it is still available for the "old-school" _vti_bin/ListData.svc.
See samples: http://platinumdogs.me/2013/03/14/sharepoint-adventures-with-the-rest-api-part-1/#paging
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45719/paging-using-rest-odata-with-sp-2013
http://www.sharepointempower.com/Blog/Post/15/Paging-using-SharePoint-2013-REST-API

Comment: Could you give an example with code for pagination

Comment: @MehdiJalal the explanation above should be a sufficient starting point IMHO, after all you might want to implement this in smart-table, ng-grid, ngtable or the other pals and so the code would be quite different. However I will oblige and spoon-feed you as soon as I get home from work in some hours

Comment: it is not working it just display: {{item.Title}}  
{{page}}

Comment: Have you checked your console? Could it be a problem with copy/paste programming? Anyway, here is some code you can add directly into script editor Web Part, just to get you going: https://gist.github.com/eirikb/9961411d6e879b943eb2

Comment: In console I get error:  RangeError: Invalid array length
    at Function.h.range (underscore.js:628)
    at PANJ.aspx:763
    at angular.js:12914
    at h.$eval (angular.js:14123)
    at h.$digest (angular.js:13939)
    at h.$apply (angular.js:14227)
    at p (angular.js:9493)
    at J (angular.js:9678)
    at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (angular.js:9621)angular.js:11358 (anonymous function)

Answer (score 1):

This part:
**$skiptoken: "Paged=TRUE&p_ID=" + ((page - 1) * itemLimit)**
is not going to work as you can expect.
If you remove any item on the list/library or change the sort order, it won't work.
The only thing which works at the moment is to get **data.d.__next** which contains link to the next page.
You can eventually store link to previous page, so thus you can get two way paging, but without "jump" to page number X.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this](http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js) plugin and try as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table table-bordered').dataTable( {
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
} );
} );
```

[Reference](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html)

Comment: No I don't want data tables

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
        $.widget("zpd.paging", {
            options: {
                limit: 5,
                rowDisplayStyle: 'block',
                activePage: 0,
                rows: []
            },
            _create: function() {
                var rows = $("tbody", this.element).children();
                this.options.rows = rows;
                this.options.rowDisplayStyle = rows.css('display');
                var nav = this._getNavBar();
                this.element.after(nav);
                this.showPage(0);
            },
            _getNavBar: function() {
                var rows = this.options.rows;
                var nav = $('<div>', {class: 'paging-nav'});
                for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(rows.length / this.options.limit); i++) {
                    this._on($('<a>', {
                        href: '#',
                        text: (i + 1),
                        "data-page": (i)
                    }).appendTo(nav),
                            {click: "pageClickHandler"});
                }
                //create previous link
                this._on($('<a>', {
                    href: '#',
                    text: '<<',
                    "data-direction": -1
                }).prependTo(nav),
                        {click: "pageStepHandler"});
                //create next link
                this._on($('<a>', {
                    href: '#',
                    text: '>>',
                    "data-direction": +1
                }).appendTo(nav),
                        {click: "pageStepHandler"});
                return nav;
            },
            showPage: function(pageNum) {
                var num = pageNum * 1; //it has to be numeric
                this.options.activePage = num;
                var rows = this.options.rows;
                var limit = this.options.limit;
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    if (i >= limit * num && i < limit * (num + 1)) {
                        $(rows[i]).css('display', this.options.rowDisplayStyle);
                    } else {
                        $(rows[i]).css('display', 'none');
                    }
                }
            },
            pageClickHandler: function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(event.target).siblings().attr('class', "");
                $(event.target).attr('class', "selected-page");
                var pageNum = $(event.target).attr('data-page');
                this.showPage(pageNum);
            },
            pageStepHandler: function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                //get the direction and ensure it's numeric
                var dir = $(event.target).attr('data-direction') * 1;
                var pageNum = this.options.activePage + dir;
                //if we're in limit, trigger the requested pages link
                if (pageNum >= 0 && pageNum < this.options.rows.length) {
                    $("a[data-page=" + pageNum + "]", $(event.target).parent()).click();
                }
            }
        });
    }); })(jQuery);
```

### CSS:

```
.paging-nav {   text-align: right;   padding-top: 2px; }

.paging-nav a {   margin: auto 1px;   text-decoration: none;   display: inline-block;   padding: 1px 7px;   background: #91b9e6;   color: white;   border-radius: 3px; }

.paging-nav .selected-page {   background: #187ed5;   font-weight: bold; }

.paging-nav,
#divdynamic {   width: 400px;   margin: 0 auto;   font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
}
```

https://peakfinders.blogspot.com/2015/12/table-pagination-using-htmlcss-in.html?showComment=1604922132794#c3421701014647177502