# Issue with $skip in REST API

Tags: 2013, rest

Here is a sample list i am using

[image]

I am testing some REST filters in the browser directly and checking the XML feed returned by the REST request. Below is the REST query which I used to get the first two items of the list and this works perfectly.

```
http://sharepointsite/sites/POC/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('samplelist')/items?$filter=Designation eq 'Developer' and Company eq 'Some Corp'
```

Now I used $top=1 at the end which also worked well and returned only the first item.

```
http://sharepointsite/sites/POC/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('samplelist')/items?$filter=Designation eq 'Developer' and Company eq 'Some Corp'&$top=1
```

However, instead of $top=1 when I use $skip=1, the feed still returns the first two items.

```
http://sharepointsite/sites/POC/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('samplelist')/items?$filter=Designation eq 'Developer' and Company eq 'Some Corp'&$skip=1
```

Where is this going wrong ?

**UPDATE**

Apparently this has been moved to the "investigation queue". [Here](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/5696072-sharepoint-2013-rest-why-doesn-t-skip-work) is a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $skip parameter does not work in SharePoint 2013 for list items. It only works for collection of data (like list collections, etc).

[Paging using REST/OData with SP 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45719/paging-using-rest-odata-with-sp-2013)

A workaround is to use `__next` property which gives you the next URL you should query.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964936/using-skip-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api

Comment: So the skip example given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx) is actually wrong !!

Comment: @VipulKelkar, if it is not working for you with the same syntax. Then that means its not supported. I can't test currently to confirm.

Comment: What do you mean by Collection of data? Are list items not a collection of data? That line does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is with URL encoding,  This url works:

**https://[YOURSITE]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('updates')/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_ID%3d2&%24top=2**

But this decoded version does not:

**https://[YOURSITE]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('updates')/items?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=2&$top=2**

Comment: Just to clarify for others, the p_ID is referring to the previous item's ID value, not the page number.