# SharePoint Online REST API List Items Paging

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Can anyone confirm that they are able to page against a SharePoint Online List Items query? Either I'm not understanding how this query is supposed to work or it just doesn't work.

```
tenant.sharepoint.com/conversations/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&amp;P_ID=2
```

I'm leveraging the documentation [here](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests) but when using Postman, all items are returned in the same query response. For example, according to the `$skiptoken` P_ID=2 above, I'm expecting a response without item ID 1. However, I still get ID 1, 2, and 3 in the response.

Comment: If you're not opposed to using ListData.svc, this still works in Online https://sjrb.sharepoint.com/sites/welcome/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/FAQ?$skip=4&$top=5

Comment: Interesting, that does work and will probably move forward with this. Thanks!

However, I'm still curious to see if anyone's been able to use the REST API to do the same.

Comment: You're supposed to be able to add the same "top" query string, but it doesn't work for me either

Comment: Hmm looks like I was missing out on some URI encoding. This works: tenant.sharepoint.com/conversations/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3DTRUE%26p_ID%3D1&%24top=5

Comment: there ya go, nice solution!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Needed URI encoding on the $shiptoken parameters - related to this post: [Paging using REST/OData with SP 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45719/paging-using-rest-odata-with-sp-2013)

```
tenant.sharepoint.com/conversations/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3DTRUE%26p_ID%3D1&%24top=5
```

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution

Comment: Note: "shiptoken" should be "skiptoken." I don't have enough rep to make a 1 character change ;-)