# Paging in sharepoint 2013 for JAVA REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, paging, java-api, java, list-view-paging

I'm trying to implement sharepoint pagination in a way that you send how many items to skip and retrieve the next n number of items. Is there a way to go about it?

```
  https://sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=substringof(%27a%27,Title)
```

I need an implementation like skip and top for this url
Edit:Can't use $skiptoken since ID's are not in sync and might cause variable amount of responses

Comment: Do a search for "SharePoint REST API paging" and you will find answers to your question. Here is one example https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218129/sharepoint-online-rest-api-list-items-paging

Comment: that answer does not satisfy my question

Comment: to the people marking this as duplicate. Do you think the answer in the other question even remotely satisfies my question?

Comment: The SharePoint REST API does not support using `$skip` and `$top` for server side paging of list items. `$skiptoken` is your only option.

Comment: can $skiptoken be used as count of a column?