# CAML - List Item Pagination in SharePoint 2016

Tags: caml-query

I've got a .NET application that needs to retrieve items from a list and return them, I'm looking for a way to paginate the results in case the number of items gets too large.

I've checked out multiple questions about it, most are from 2013 saying the only way is to compare the last ID retrieved, but I also see that there's a REST [skiptoken](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/128885/76833) property that works in a similar way, but can't find a CAML equivalent.

Is my only solution just doing something like this?

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' /> <Value Type="ModStat">0</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Gt>
            <FieldRef Name='ID' /> <Value Type="Number">{lastId}</Value>
        </Gt>
    </And>
</Where>
<RowLimit>10</RowLimit>
```

Comment: maybe have a look at ListItemCollectionPosition. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177592/how-to-query-list-with-5000-items-in-sharepoint-online/177593 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132229/get-sharepoint-list-in-batches-c-sharp-csom

Answer (score 0):

SPQuery has a `ListItemCollectionPosition` property that is used for pagination. Using it is a best practice for getting large numbe of list items without blocking the content database.

**Helper Method that gets all items in a large SharePoint list**

```
private static void GetAllItems(SPList list, int itemCount, SPQuery query, string lastItemIdOnPage, List<SPListItem> listItems)
{
    while (true)
    {
        query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
        query.RowLimit = (uint)itemCount;
        if (lastItemIdOnPage != null)
        {
            SPListItemCollectionPosition pos = new SPListItemCollectionPosition(lastItemIdOnPage);
            query.ListItemCollectionPosition = pos;
        }

        SPListItemCollection spListItems = list.GetItems(query);
        if (spListItems == null)
        {
            itemCount = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (spListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition == null)
            {
                listItems.AddRange(spListItems.Cast<SPListItem>());
                break;
            }

            lastItemIdOnPage = spListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition.PagingInfo;
            itemCount = spListItems.Count;
            listItems.AddRange(spListItems.Cast<SPListItem>());
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
List<SPListItem> listItems = new List<SPListItem>();
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = @"
                <Where>
                    <And>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' /> <Value Type='ModStat'>0</Value>
                        </Eq>
                        <Gt>
                            <FieldRef Name='ID' /> <Value Type='Number'>{lastId}</Value>
                        </Gt>
                    </And>
                </Where>
                <RowLimit>10</RowLimit>";

int itemCount = 500;

GetAllItems(list, itemCount, query, null, listItems);
return listItems;
```